# 100% - /tmp help needed

Tags: hard-drive, centos5, disk-space-utilization

few hours back i receievd message from directadmin

```
 Warning: The disk usage for one or more of your partitions is running low
```

so i checked in directadmin and noticed this message

```
Subject: Warning: The disk usage for one or more of your partitions is running low  Today at 00:10

This is an automated message notifying you that the following partition(s) have exceeded the 95% threshold:

100% - /tmp


================================
Automated Message Generated by DirectAdmin
```

i am running CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
with 8 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD

my /etc/fstab

```
[root@www tmp]# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=/                 /                       ext3    defaults,usrquota,grpquota      1 1
LABEL=/tmp              /tmp                    ext3    defaults        1 2
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext2    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda3         swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/root/myswapfile               swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

df shows this

```
[root@www tmp]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            466893488 166706136 276087844  38% /
/dev/sda5              2030736   2030708         0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda1               101086     14155     81712  15% /boot
tmpfs                  4026368         0   4026368   0% /dev/shm
```

i checked /tmp with

```
 ls -Sahl /tmp |more
```

and got

```
[root@www tmp]#  ls -Sahl /tmp |more
total 2.0G
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 08:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-16899-1358668712
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 17 19:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-32627-1358449117
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 00:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-11269-1358812717
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 04:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-13883-1358654312
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 19 15:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-15165-1358607512
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 07:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-16193-1358665112
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 19 17:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-16967-1358614712
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 09:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-17504-1358672313
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 10:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-18150-1358675912
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 10:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-18524-1358848717
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 19 20:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-19700-1358625512
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 12:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-19935-1358855917
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 19 21:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-20411-1358629112
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 20 03:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-26888-1358650712
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 21 17:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-6838-1358787512
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 21 18:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-7461-1358791117
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 21 23:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-10360-1358809117
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 18 03:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-11390-1358477917
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 01:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-11937-1358816317
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 02:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-12567-1358819917
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 17 21:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-1300-1358456317
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 22 03:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-13288-1358823517
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 19 13:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-13525-1358600313
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 18 05:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-13562-1358485117
```

also multiple files are like this

```
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 21:50 sess_ba965ac806041ebd29ad8c99988418e9
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 20:45 sess_baaeae941c84380955cf3f02ff3f8aef
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 22:41 sess_bb25eb1fef8c60c3b7c8b10c0fa54936
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 23:11 sess_bba27c9741ade77c1fd71ecce7670d52
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 21:32 sess_bc21bc743a742c5673bbcc82497de6f0
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 23 00:16 sess_bd2570876122061fbbf699bbd9c08a24
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 23:31 sess_bd25c6ad08efebdc8b16671d482e82ac
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 21:03 sess_bdcdb94427220cdedd79cb9e3ae2328c
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 21:34 sess_be21461e86f8c750ae33b3ba2a6d8291
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 23:54 sess_bec63e0e7850e7754da45b6843b6e6e7
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 23:50 sess_bf4049482ced6b38c9565f4a4827ea5c
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 22 23:42 sess_bf810cb007c0fc84b3d55b5f3ec39977
-rw-------  1 apache webapps    0 Jan 23 00:24 sess_bfd5315a423e43337d9a95c327d15070
```

how can i solve this ?

so is it ok to delete files from /tmp
or is it possible to increase the /tmp size if deleting files gonna cause issue to my system.

can i delete sess_ files also ?

Thanks for your time.

=============================================================================

Update:

i just did

```
[root@www tmp]# rm -f core-yum-updatesd-he*
```

cause new sessions couldnt be created and i wasnt able to login to some of my scripts using sessions.

so now my df looks like this

```
[root@www tmp]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            466893488 166706704 276087276  38% /
/dev/sda5              2030736     48644   1877272   3% /tmp
/dev/sda1               101086     14155     81712  15% /boot
tmpfs                  4026368         0   4026368   0% /dev/shm
```

any input would be great, regarding how can i stop this in future.

thanks

=========================================================================================
update

i did

```
 /etc/init.d/yum-updatesd stop
```

and then

```
 chkconfig --levels 2345 yum-updatesd off
```

as suggested by "ewwhite".

as it was creating new same files like this

```
[root@www tmp]#  ls -Sahl /tmp |more
total 44M
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 23 01:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-27658-1358902717
-rw-------  1 root   root     47M Jan 23 00:58 core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-27034-1358899117
```

cat /etc/issue gives this

```
[root@www tmp]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Thanks for your help.
i am watching if new files are being created again.
i dont know what might be causing this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Yum updates daemon is crashing. This program runs in the background to check for updated software. Disable it. (`service yum-updatesd stop` then `chkconfig yum-updatesd off` or deselect it in `ntsysv`). You can safely remove the core files in /tmp (`rm -f core-yum-updatesd*`).

What version of CentOS is this? Can you provide the output of `cat /etc/issue`?

Comment: okie, i am running CentOS release 5.7 (Final) with 8 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD

Comment: here it is [root@www tmp]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

Comment: is that directadmin calling yum-updatesd ? or is it just inbuilt process to check updated software ? thans

Comment: just checked these files are keep on generating core-yum-updatesd-he-11-0-0-27658-1358902717 , i have stopped yum-updatesd by doing chkconfig yum-updatesd off

Comment: how can i know the cause of update daemon crashing ? thanks

Comment: `service yum-updatesd stop`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up rpm database, maybe something is corrupted.

```
yum clean all
mv /var/cache/yum/ /some/backup/folder
mv /var/lib/rpm/__db* /some/backup/folder
rpm –rebuilddb
```

I had some problems with yum-updatesd cpu usage (on CentOS 5) because of rpm database.

Comment: is this safe for system ? i mean wont it mess up with my preinstalled apps ? thanks

Comment: It shouldn't mess up anything. This files will be recreated (http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/RPM_Guide-Using_RPM_DB-rebuilding_RPM-db.html). And you make a backup before doing anything.